# Histogram to show the count per month or day in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a histogram that shows count of event on date for each month so i can see the total for each month. When I create the histogram the left hand side is a density instead of a count.

How to a get a graph that shows total number of a date per month

Example code (rough indication only)

```
data_toview <- read.csv("file_with_data.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#Distribution of count per day, so i know how the data can spike
hist(data_toview$interesting_date, breaks =  "days")
```

[image]

Not i may be using the wrong plot type that is why i did not specify histogram in the question title.  Also any suggestions to get the months on the labels.

Comment: Don't use a histogram, use a `barplot()`. Once you've got a `table` by day.

Comment: Shouldn't you also be able to explicitly specify `hist(...,freq=T)`?

Comment: That's the answer, thanks.  barplot also works but it requires a little more data manipulation before hand.